# IIS8 provides wrong certificate through SNI

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012, sni

I am using IIS8 for managing around 20 sites on one IP. I use SNI to distinguish the requests and leading them to their directories.

I created 20 SSL Certs by letsEncrypt and linked all my pages.

Page 1 has: No IP binding, no SNI, using Cert MAIN
Page 2 has: No IP binding, SNI, www.page2.com, using CERT PAGE2CERT
Page 3 has: No IP binding, SNI, www.page3.com, using CERT PAGE3CERT
and so on...

Page 1 works fine, SSL connection is safe, loads correct cert Main and address bar is green.
Page 2-20 working with their http binding, but fail with https: Provided was Cert MAIN instead of PAGEXXCERT.

I tried setting bindings, enabling SNI for Page1, but this is not working either.

What can I do to simply make SNI working and providing the correct Certs to the clients? My test browsers are recently updated and provide SNI. When I get my SSL Error, I can click on "Visit this site (unsafe)" and it is connecting to https://page2.com to the correct directory. So SNI should work. But the cert is still the false one.

Thanks for your help
Karsten

Comment: Karsten, did you ever get this sorted out? I'm having the exact same problem and it drives me nuts...